# Might security not be a crosscutting concern?

Tags: security, architecture

I am working on a project with very detailed security requirements. I would honestly not be surprised if the model proposed was as complex as for any intelligence/security agency. Now I've read that incorporating security with business logic is a mixing of concerns and thus a practice to be avoided.

However, all attempts at abstracting security have either failed or created "abstractions" as messy as before. Is it possible for security to be so specific that it *becomes* part of business rules? In some situations violating security, only masks the data, whereas in other situations will terminate the session, and at others time it will trigger default values to be used instead. The are many requirements that respond to security priveleges.

My fundamental question is: could I be in an exceptional case (i.e. one where incorporating security is sound) or am I not understanding something fundamental about abstracting security?

---

**Edit:**

tl;dr (of answers as I understand them): authentication (who are you) is very much a cross cutting concern and should be abstracted, whereas authorization (what can you do) is business logic. Lacking that vocabulary and having only the term "security" (or perhaps failing to appreciate the distinction between the two) lead to my confusion.

Comment: I think you'd get better response over at [ITSecurity](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I assume that when you say "security", you're not referring *just* to authentication and authorization, as both posters so far assert that is all there is to it...

Comment: Avid, I think we're not addressing other security as the post is specifically questioning whether security can be part of business rules.  Things like Sql injection attacks, while are part of "security", are addressed by coding patterns and practices as the data crosses the various layers, and not something commonly found in requirements.

Comment: @AviD I'm asking about architecture the specifics of which happen to be security. One could replace "security" with "auditting" and "logging" and one would have pretty much the same question.

Comment: @Andy: and maybe thats why things like SQL Injection is still so common - it definitely *should* be part of requirements, I always have it that way.

Comment: @ArtB, yes, of course. However when you say "security", do you mean specifically authentication and authorization? Security architecture includes a lot more than just those two... However it sounds (from your other comments) that you're looking for context-sensitive access control. While this *can* be part of your business logic, and often needs to be simply because your "security logic" is too specific for common generic tools, that doesn't necessarily have to always be the case - but if it is, that's fine.

Comment: @Avid:  It should be part of any development shops coding rules, not something the customer has to explicitly ask for.  I don't think it would be useful to list the specific vunerabilities in a contract.  I can see each side bickering over those kinds of terms.  After all, the contract only mentioned exploits X, Y and Z, but the app feel to Z'.  Do you feel like specifics on how transactions are handled (TransactionScope vs. DTC) should be in requeirements too, or should the professionals decide that?  I prefer to be told the "what", and be left to decide the "how."

Comment: @Andy, I agree with that. Not necessarily "how", or the "list of badness", however the level of expected security should be specified. See for example some of the answers to [Are all security requirements expected to be testable?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3255/33). Also relevant is this question: [How to define security requirements to ensure that developers… do not provide security by obscurity?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1581/33)

Comment: I agree that security is a broad topic, and the questions posted are important.  However, I'm not sure they belong in a requirements doc. Case in point; we have a client specifying a certain encryption algorthm.  One that has been broken and which is not as strong as others out there.  Threats change and morph, a requirements document frequently does not.  But the points you raise are important, but I felt like the context of the question was really about authentication / authorization, more than security in general.

Comment: @Andy, apparently you were correct - it looks like that *is* what the OP intended. However, I saw nothing in the question to lead to that assumption? There are many other parts of security that clearly *should* be in requirements docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security is split into two parts; authentication and authorization.  Authentication is a pretty specific use case.  How do you determine that a user is trusted out of a set of untrusted users.  I think this is cross cutting; you need to keep unauthenticated users out of your system, or a subset of your system.

Authorization (can the user do something) is very much a business rule.  It can (and often is) very specific and different to each use case.  Who determines what roles can do what?  Well, the business does.  No one else can answer that for you.

In the Csla.Net 4 framework, that's exactly how authorization is treated; as a specialized business rule.  You're not even limited to "user is in role" or "user has permission."  You can make more complex rules "user can edit this field if workflow step has not past this particular step."

Comment: "Security is split into two parts; authentication and authorization. Authentication is a pretty specific use case: I think this is cross cutting. Authorization (can the user do something) is very much a business rule." That provoked in me a moment of enlightenment, thank you.

Comment: `"Security is split into two parts; authentication and authorization"` - security is about a lot more than that.

Comment: In general yes, but those other areas don't end up becoming baked in as business rules, which authorization does.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose an exceptional case would be if your business logic IS security services of some kind then yes.  However I think your problem may be that you are confusing user authorization with authentication.

Certainly Authentication should have a set of rules associated with it but the end result should be, identification of the user and creation of the session.

Authorization would be seperate from that where we determine the user role, and what privileges are laid out by that role.

A typical example would be that Authentication returns a User object and stores it in session.  The User has 1 to many roles.  A role may have 1 to many privileges.  A business logic method might be sendEmail.  This method queries the User object for a specific privilege, if it exists do something, if not do something else.

EDIT: Security in my opinion should always be a cross cutting concern when it comes to the user, however if your business logic involves properties of objects that are not the user, CRUD of those objects, or administering other users then it falls in line with your business requirements and thus is Business Logic.

Comment: Yes, QuarterBack is a Role.  QuarterBack has a variety of associated Privileges.  RunningBack may also be a Role but RunningBack might have the same privileges.  They both may have privilege, "Run the football".  You should be able to query the User object to see if has a specific Privilege in ANY of its roles.

Comment: "I thought people were advocating for no trace of security in business code".  That statement is too generalized and I would challenge that as a general rule.  You should not be Authenticating a user in your business logic code correct.  Authorization can be handled by a global crosscutting component that your business logic can share.  It need not be any more complicated than that.

Comment: `"... confusing user authorization with authentication"` - security is about a lot more than that.